# PHP скелет для не магазинных web-приложений с MVC и ActiveRecord

Tags: php, cms, framework

История со впадением в ступор при выборе скелета - знакома тем, кто делает сайты/сервисы радикально отличающиеся от магазинов, и сайтов-блогов/визиток. В итоге скелет для каждого нового проекта получается методом "удалим всё ненужное из старого проекта, вот и скелет!". Очень хочется прервать этот замкнутый круг, ведь возможно есть качественные скелеты? Теперь к конкретике:

Под скелетом я понимаю нечто среднее между фреймворком из коробки (yii, zend например) и CMS (wordpress, bitrix например). То есть не только архитектурное устройство, что даёт фреймворк. Нужны также совсем базовые модули "под дописку". Какой скелет требуется конкретно нам, и возможно многим:

1. Основан на любом из фреймворков с `MVC`, имеет модульную структуру
2. Работа с БД идёт через `ActiveRecord`, приветствуется присутствие `ORM`
3. Имеет на борту системные модули - работа с файлами с возможностью переключать хранилище (`Storage`), группа компонентов для общих вещей (вроде тикетов техподдержки, тегов, поиска, логгирования ошибок, и.т.п. модуль `Utility`).
4. Модуль пользователя с авторизацией через соцсети, с возможностью требования некоторых перс-данных для получения полноценного статуса (`User`). Не обязательно, но желательно с модулем оповещений по СМС/на-почту/на-сайт.
5. Минималистичная работа с контент-страницами (`Article`).
6. Не обязательно, но желаемо - платёжный модуль: балланс пользователя, услуги и подписка, экваеринг (`Billing`).

Не обязательна даже админка, тем более не требуются системные вещи вроде компиляции css, сборка react (как в magento).

Проблема в том, что в основной массе для web штампуются интернет-магазины, блоги, и визитки. Как только появляется необходимость иного сервиса - нам вот приходится либо тянуть громоздкий код за собой, либо писать с нуля(неизвестно даже что быстрее и лучше выходит). Можно было бы обрезать модули одной из существующих CMS - но во первых: не помню бесплатных CMS, которые активно используют `ActiveRecord` (это важное требование), во вторых они все очень избыточны запутаны: то есть апгрейд заточен там под обновления от авторов CMS/модулей и настройку модулей, а не под "дописку" кода. И даже если несмотря на всё выбрать дописку CMS - это отказ от обновления - а это в свою очередь делает систему недолговечной в плане безопасности.

Но может быть мы отстали, и подобных качественных скелетов уже много? Или в общем альтернатив нет? Подскажите пожалуйста, на какие продукты стоит обратить внимание.

*P.S. Вопрос не совсем в тематике SO, так как предполагает в ответе мнение о скелете, тем не менее для автора он очень горяч и актуален.*

Comment: Вопрос из серии "на чём разрабатывать PHP сайты в 2018 году". Предлагаю накидать качественных ответов и считать эталонной закрывашкой ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я могу порекомендовать обратить внимание на фреймворк Laravel в связке с админкой Sleeping Owl для создания типовых crud-операций.

Laravel -- один из наиболее популярных PHP-движков в Европе, сейчас это там стандарт де факто. В качестве подтверждения могу привести линк на [stackoverflow trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=laravel%2Csymfony%2Cyii).

Каким вашим требованиям удовлетворяет:

- модульная структура
- mvc из коробки (впрочем, это сейчас во всех популярных движках), поддержка роутингов, контроллеров, миддлвари и т.п.
- ActiveRecord из коробки и ORM из коробки (с учётом модульности -- можно заменять на другие варианты)
- имеет модуль работы с файловой системой (абстракция, которая поддерживает не только локальные файлы, но и работу с облачными файловыми системами)
- интеграция с соцсетями из коробки, возможно придётся для каких-то соцсеток писать собственные провайдеры -- но проще поставить пакет Socialite

Crud-админки не являются частью движка, нужно ставить сторонние решения поверх. Одна из самых популярных админок -- Sleeping Owl, поддерживается русскоязычным коммьюнити, шлёпать админки с ней -- одно удовольствие.

Работа с контент-страницами тоже часть админки -- поэтому описываю в этом пункте.

Чего нет в коробке:

- Работа с тикетами
- Билинг
- Корзина покупок (можно поискать готовые модули, например [Crinsane](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) или создать свой)

Comment: Спасибо, полезный обзор laravel ! У нас даже есть сайт на нём, но в возможности особо не углублялись.

Comment: Особо не углублялся, но: [Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing)

Answer (score 3):

Первое, что приходит в голову - [MaxSite CMS](http://max-3000.com/page/max)
, сама по себе освнована на MVC фреймворке CodeIgniter и ориентирована как раз на то, что дописывать модули и виджеты будете сами. а по большому счету полностью универсальных решений не бывает, тут либо смириться с недостатками существующих CMS, или писать что-то свое под свои цели

Comment: Пробежавшись быстро по корешку архива - не увидел там не то что ActiveRecord - даже MVC. Но за совет - спасибо. Ещё одно - `смириться с недостатками существующих CMS` если CMS бесплатная, то смирение с ней, и с тем что её код будет менятьсяя - равносильно отказу от обновлений, что в свою очередь равносильно дырам в безопасности через некоторое время.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр у них в основе CMS лежит MVC фреймворк, то есть при создании какого-либо модуля можно спокойно использовать функционал фреймворка, а это и ActiveRecord, и прочие ништячки. Вопрос опять же в том, надо ли вам такой гемморой или проще уже написать эту самую основу самому, чтобы потом использовать в проектах

Comment: Не, то что у них в основе лежит MVC фреймворк - это не значит что они MVC используют в принципе. Но mvc там нету - там я так понял основу деления представляет плагин, который в отличие от модуля mvc содержит крохи php файлов, не являющимися классами. Классический MVC модуль состоит из разного рода классов, рассортированных по папочкам внутри папки модуля - классов около 50 на модуль, среди которых есть контроллеры, модели, и виды.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр я в курсе что такое MVC) И говорю - ни одна CMS не будет соответсвовать вашим требованиям полностью) Просто эта более универсальная и не заточена под магазинчики, а позволяет себя расширять как вам угодно. Сам лично давно от подобных комбайнов отказался и пишу на чистом symfony, потому как лень разбираться с их обновлениями и постоянными отваливаниями модулей и прочего

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую Yii2 фреймворк. На мой взгляд, это лучшая платформа из всех фреймворков и CMS с которыми я когда-либо работал. Там есть все, о чем вы просили. Если будете выбирать фреймворк, то только Yii2, и никакой ни Laravel, как пишут в другом ответе! Там и половины нет тех возможностей, что есть в Yii2. Перечислю основные плюсы специально в вашем контексте:

1. Мощный встроенный инструмент генерации кода. Админки любой сложности
   штампуются на раз, и безо всяких ошибок в коде.
2. Расширений под Yii написано масса, и это далеко не базовые модули. Найти можно все что угодно.

ActiveRecord, Виджеты, RESTful API, генерация документации, PJAX с которым вообще забываешь про написание AJAX-ов в backend, мощная система ролей RBAC, I18N со сканированием всего проекта, разделение приложения на frontend и backend и много другого.
Один минус - порог вхождения не малый. В тот же Laravel гораздо проще стартануть, но и возможностей будет намного меньше.

Удачи с выбором! ;)

Comment: Спасибо конечно `специально в вашем контексте` но мне не нужны админки и генерация кода :) Про Yii мне известно, вопрос не во фреймворке, вопрос в  наличии качественной сборки фреймворка - скелетона. Крайне желательно, чтобы было удобно расширять любой кусок кода. То что вы написали про Yii - это базовый набор любого фреймворка - например в Zend3 от создателей PHP ещё больше фич, только готовую сборку со всем реально нужным для стартапа на борту никто сделать не посмел) Может быть вы дополните ответ и укажете ссылку на сборку-пример?